# Sitecore SXA Pass Through Field how to get actual Item?

Tags: sxa

If I want to render the image url in a data-attribute (lets assume the Image Field is called TeaserImage) I can render the Media URL by `$(TeaserImage)`. So far so good.

Now I have a reference field for my image because I need the Alt text from the media item. For the data-scr attribute I need the media url of the Image Field I have passed through. `$(Item)` does not work. Should be something like `$(this)`?

How can I get the actual item that I have passed through?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this ootb...  unless you are on 9.3 and are able to use Scriban.

There is a workaround though - but it's a dirty hack and maybe not upgrade-proof. I used to have an issue where I had to use a data attribute in a section to get a value from a referenced item - which also didn't work as those attributes work on text fields only.

After some discussion with Support and the Sxa team, we found a solution by overriding a part of the `RenderVariantField` pipeline. In our case the variant was a section, so we had to override RenderSection. Seems to be the same in your case (looking at the image).

You can override the `GetAttributeTokenValue` function (which expects a fieldname and item) to implement your needed logic and then return to the base logic. If I understand correctly you should "invent" some name as you do not need an actual field value.

More info on my blog: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2018/10/using-tokens-in-sitecore-sxa-variant.html

Comment: Thank you I will have a look into it.